# How to create a downward grid system

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, layout, grid

Somebody help me ? i very stuck, i wanna create grid using bootstrap

How to create position like this ?

[image]

I try to create using col md, and the result like this

[image]

```
           @foreach($pallet as $row)
                @if($row->slot_status == 'Tersedia')
                    <div class="col-xs-1-5" style="margin-bottom:5vh;">
                        <a href="{{ url('admin-master/detail_slot/'. $row->id_slot) }}" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%;">{{ $row->pallet_name }}</a>
                    </div>

                @endif
                @if($row->slot_status == 'Penuh')
                    <div class="col-xs-1-5" style="margin-bottom:5vh;">
                        <a href="{{ url('admin-master/detail_slot/'. $row->id_slot) }}" class="btn btn-danger" style="width:100%;">{{ $row->pallet_name }}</a>
                    </div>
                @endif
            @endforeach
```

I used laravel for got data from database
please help me

Comment: can you add the html ?

Comment: suree, my html like this https://postimg.cc/s1BW7bvz

Comment: Please add your Code as Code into the question rather then using images.

Comment: I have added the code to my question

Comment: Thats not the way bootstrap cols work. you can add a `col-1` to `col-12` for every breakpoint.

Comment: You should to write static markup first, that matches the given structure. Then add the Laravel parts. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

use these class here is an example

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="w-100"></div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
</div>
```

use this to break space between two div

```html
 <style >
            .col {
                padding: 50px;
            }
        </style>
```

here is bootstrap example.
[tutorial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)